# I'm using tailwindCSS for a simple html site but deployment on netlify does not work, why?

Tags: web, deployment, web-deployment, netlify, tailwind-css

I've been learning how to use tailwind css by following the offical video tutorial and I just wanted to try to deploy the site example to Netlify to see if it works using the drag and drop feature.

This means taking the entire project folder and dumping it into netlify. This usually works with vanilla html css js sites but for some reason I get the error 
`Page Not Found Looks like you've followed a broken link or entered a URL that doesn't exist on this site.`

This is how the project structured looked like:

[image: project structure]

What am I doing wrong? Inside the build folder there is another file called tailwind.css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On your Netlify dashboard, change the `publish directory` to the directory where your `index.html` file resides:  `public/`. That should do it.

You can also, as you said, take everything out of the public folder and put it at the same level as the other folder and files, which makes the index.html available at the root of the project. However, then you lose your project's file organization.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the problem.

The trick was to take everything out of the public folder and put it at the same level as the other folder and files.

This would make the index.html file available at the root of the project and would allow the site to work properly once deployed.